I want to do something using notification data when tapped on notification when app is running. How do I implement this in flutter
I have setup firebase push notifications and notifications are receiving in my flutter app. this is how I have handled it.
Future<void> init() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      iosInit();
    } else {
      await androidInit();
    }

    getInitialMsg();

    //when app in background
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((msg) {
      handleRoutingOnNotificationTap(msg.data);
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      showNotification(message);
    });
  }

I call this init() before runApp().
I use flutter_local_notifications plugin to show notifications in foreground. Because by default it doesn't show notification when notification received when app is in foreground. In background system show notification by default. I don't manually show.
void showNotification(RemoteMessage msg) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = msg.notification;
    if (notification == null) return;
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().show(
      ...,
      payload: msg.data.toString(),
    );
  }

I receive notifications in both background and foreground. I want to implement some navigation logic using notification data payload. In current implementation this only works when app is launched from tapping on a notification(which launches the app) when app is in background. I can use this listener for that >
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((msg) {
  handleRoutingOnNotificationTap(msg.data);
});

there's no listener for when notification tapped when app is running?
So in summary what I want to implement is when notification recieving when app is running(foreground) and user taps it > should handle some navigation logic. How do I implement this?

Found the answer. We can use onDidReceiveNotificationResponse of flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin. we can pass a payload string(jsonencoded) in show(...,payload: jsonEncode(msg.data)) to show notificaton(and pass payload) and we can handle this payload in onDidReceiveNotificationResponse callback.
`flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onDidReceiveNotificationResponse);`

